# Audio cutting out in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

I currently have an issue in my WPF application. I am trying to play a .mp3 audio file in the background of my window and I've run into a wierd issue. My sound cuts out at random, this issue seems to be due to some kind of windows setting? Because some computers I run it on have the issue while some don't. This is my code:

```
        InitializeComponent();
        MediaPlayer muziek = new MediaPlayer();
        muziek.Open(new Uri(@"song.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
        muziek.Play();
```

Any thoughts? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Please try and provide a [mcve]. From the snippet, I doubt the question is answerable.

Comment: That's kind of the issue, I currently don't have more code than this. I'm going to try to fix this before I continue

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the MediaPlayer object as a private variable of the class rather than defined in the body of the code. It could be that the MediaPlayer object is being garbage collected as it thinks it has dropped out of scope. Depending on the memory pressure the machine is under garbage collection might happen at different times (or not at all) which explains the behaviour you are seeing